# statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.X13Error: ERROR: Number of user-defined X elements= 166 not equal to a multiple of the number of columns= 4

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, statsmodels, x13

My test data has two columns `M0` and `exog` (You can download the X13 software and test data from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v4adf86g2rqzan5/X13_data.zip?dl=0)).

```
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os

X13PATH = r'D:\data\X13'
os.chdir(X13PATH)
os.environ['X13PATH'] = X13PATH
print(os.environ['X13PATH'])

file_path = '../test_data/X13_test_data.xlsx'
sheet_name = 'Sheet1'

df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=sheet_name, index_col='date')
print(df.head(5))

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)
# df = df.rename(columns={'festival_factor': 'exog', 'M0': 'endog'})
res = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], exog=df['exog'], x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)
# res = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)
print(res.seasadj)
print(res.plot)
```

Out:

```
                  M0      exog
date                          
2009-07-31  34239.30  0.000000
2009-08-31  34406.62  0.000000
2009-09-30  36787.89  0.333333
2009-10-31  35730.23  0.516129
2009-11-30  36343.86  0.000000

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\data\X13_test.py", line 19, in <module>
    res = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], exog=df['exog'], x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 210, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 518, in x13_arima_analysis
    _check_errors(errors)
  File "D:\Program Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 201, in _check_errors
    raise X13Error(errors)
statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.X13Error: ERROR: Number of user-defined X elements= 166
        not equal to a multiple of the number of columns=  4.
```

I use `sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], exog=df['exog'], x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)` to perform X13 ARIMA on `M0` For seasonal adjustment, the `exog` column is used as an **exogenous variable**, but an error occurs: `statsmodels.tools.sm_exceptions.X13Error: ERROR: Number of user-defined X elements= 166 not equal to a multiple of the number of columns= 4.`

My analysis found that the main cause of the error is caused by `exog=df['exog']`, because `sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)` can run normally.

How to deal with this error? Thanks.

**Update:**

```
res = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], exog=df['exog'].values, x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)
```

Out:

```
                  M0      exog
date                          
2009-07-31  34239.30  0.000000
2009-08-31  34406.62  0.000000
2009-09-30  36787.89  0.333333
2009-10-31  35730.23  0.516129
2009-11-30  36343.86  0.000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\X13_test.py", line 34, in <module>
    res = sm.tsa.x13_arima_analysis(endog=df['M0'], exog=df['exog'].values, x12path=X13PATH, print_stdout=True)
  File "C:\Users\LSTM\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 210, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Program Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 497, in x13_arima_analysis
    spec += _make_regression_options(trading, exog)
  File "D:\Program Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 180, in _make_regression_options
    var_names = _make_var_names(exog)
  File "D:\Program Files\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\x13.py", line 159, in _make_var_names
    raise ValueError("exog is not a Series or DataFrame or is unnamed.")
ValueError: exog is not a Series or DataFrame or is unnamed.
```

Comment: Hi, what happens with `exog=df['exog'].values`?

Comment: @Laurent I updated in the end of the question, it returns `ValueError: exog is not a Series or DataFrame or is unnamed.`